# File Transformation in WSO2 ESB

Tags: apache, wso2, wso2-esb

Is it possible in WSO2 ESB to transform file from one format to another format?(ex: txt to csv) I need to route some files from one system to another system, but I want the files to be transformed before they arrive in the target. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [smooks](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB451/Sample+654%3a+Smooks+Mediator) mediator to transform into csv

Comment: thanks..how about transform into another format? is it possible? do i have to write my own mediator class?

Comment: what are the other fromats you want to transform, you may need to enable message for matters if you like to get messages in formats like, json

Comment: I need to change the file's content format as the business required..how can I do this?do I need to write my own custom mediation class?